# I am making a website in React js and there is a space occurring between body and scroll bar when site refreshes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scrollbar

So here is the image can anyone help me out
[This is the image where there is this problem with scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XapL.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide some more information about what you tried and maybe try sharing your CSS code.

Comment: Without any code I don't think you'll get much help. Could be any number of things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the width of the image to 100% using CSS.

```
.image-element{
    width: 100%;
}
```